# How can I get a list of all misspelled words in a text using Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim

I have a text that has a number of misspelled words. I'd like to get a list of all those words, so for a text like this:

```
This is just a normall line with some speling mistakes in it.
```

It would return:

```
normall speling
```

Is there way to do that, preferably using Linux tools, like aspell or vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `aspell -a` to do this, and take the file from stdout.  This will output the word with line number and alternate spellings:

```
cat example.txt | aspell -a
```

To clean up your list better, I'd use something more like:

```
cat aspell.txt | aspell -a | cut --delimiter ' ' --fields 2 | grep --invert-match '*'
```

Explaining the second set of commands:
The output of `aspell -a` has a `*` for correctly spelled words, and mispelled words have output like this:

```
& dev 26 101: Devi, derv, DEC, Dec, deb, DE, def, div, Dave, dive, dove, DEA, Dee, dew, Del, Dem, Nev, Rev, deg, den, rev, Davy, deaf, defy, diva, TV
```

`dev` is the misspelled word here, which is in the second "column" when delimiting by spaces. So we pipe the `aspell` output to `cut` to get only the second column.  We also pipe to `grep` to remove all the lines with `*`.

You can also append `| sort | uniq` to list misspelled words only once even if they appear in the text multiple times.

Comment: Please explain what your second set of commands do.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wanted to do this but I wasn’t particularly happy with the accepted
answer so I researched the issue and came up with the following solutions,
using four common spelling libraries/utilities.

Note: all quotes are from the man page for that particular utility.

---

#### Ispell

> The `-l` or `list` option to ispell is used to produce a list of misspelled
>   words from the standard input.

Input redirection can be used to read from a file:

```
ispell -l <example.txt
```

---

#### Aspell

One of aspell’s commands is `list` which, similar to the above ispell option, is used to

> Produce a list of misspelled words from standard input.

This can also be combined with input redirection:

```
aspell list <example.txt
```

---

#### Hunspell

Hunspell also implements the `-l` option:

> The "list" option is used to produce a list of misspelled words from the
>   standard input.

While experimenting, I noticed it can also be used with a filename as an
argument (without the need for input redirection):

```
hunspell -l example.txt
```

---

#### Enchant

Abiword’s Enchant spell-checker also supports the `-l` option:

> List only the misspellings.

Likewise, Enchant also accepts a filename as an argument (while defaulting to
standard input, if none provided):

```
enchant -l example.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

My [SpellCheck plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844) has a `:SpellCheck` command that populates Vim's *quickfix* list with all spelling errors. You can then use Vim's built-in commands to navigate that list, or use mappings provided by the plugin to fix those errors directly from the list.